# What version of ubuntu is to be installed in dell-mini-10?

Tags: 12.04, dell

I am using Dell Ubuntu Mini 10 version of Ubuntu.

**The problem is:**
I tried both 12.04 and 13.04, but both are extremely slow on this laptop.So I am now running 11.04 which is near it's End Of Life and will give no further support.

So what should I do now? Is there any better option than using 11.04?

Comment: You can try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, also, 12.04 with unity-2d should run well.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Why don't you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered in the comments by mike:

```
You can try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, also, 12.04 with unity-2d should run well.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Xubuntu or Lubuntu 14.04 or 15.04. Both should run well, be reasonable though, it's not going to be a speed demon, no matter what you install.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the recommended distro for the Dell Mini10 netbook
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/9.10/ubuntu-9.10-netbook-remix-i386.iso

Here is tha page on the Ubuntu Wiki that details distros for Netbooks:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks